# Bash ? appears when array is created from readarray but not manually declared

Tags: arrays, bash

I have a file (my_ID_file) of IDs, one ID per line, no other excess white white spaces. it was created from using the cut command form another file. the file looks like 101 lines of this...

```
PA10 
PA102 
PA103 
PA105  
PA107 
PA109
```

I am trying to use these IDs in a for loop to create a directory structure. so I use the readarray function as such to create the array...

```
readarray TIDs < my_ID_file
```

and then use a for loop as such to create the directory structure...

```
for T in "${TIDs[@]}"
do
mkdir "$T"_folder
done
```

this produces directories named....

```
PA10?_folder
PA102?_folder 
PA103?_folder 
PA105?_folder 
PA107?_folder 
PA109?_folder
```

If however I declare the array manually like....

```
TIDs=(PA10 PA102 PA103 PA105 PA107 PA109)
```

and then run the for loop I get the correct directory structure produced like....

```
PA10_folder
PA102_folder 
PA103_folder 
PA105_folder 
PA107_folder 
PA109_folder
```

Where are these question marks coming from? how can i declare arrays from files like this without having this question mark appearing in subsequent use of the array?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure there are no invisible characters in my_ID_file? Try `cat -vet my_ID_file` to make them visible.

Comment: ok thanks, I couldnt find them when copying to text wrangler, but using this method $ suffixes each line i.e. PA10$ PA102$ etc. How can I get rid of these invisible characters? and would these have been created from the cut method I used?

Comment: The `$` is normal; it's how `cat -e` displays the end of the line (so you can tell the difference between e.g. "`PA10$`" and "`PA10 $`").

Comment: The problem is `readarray` doesn't remove newlines without `-t` as glenn states below, but if you're going to use readarray, why loop at all? `mapfile -t TIDs < "my_ID_file" && mkdir -p "${TIDs[@]}"` If you do need to loop for some other reason, you may as well use `while read T; do mkdir "$T" && otherstuff; done < "my_ID_file"`.

Comment: looks like @glenn jackmanan has the answer. it is also required to be used in a nested loop and other constructs later too. Thanks all for your help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<strike>Your text file has DOS-style line endings. The "?" appear because the carriage returns would mess up `ls` output. Try `od -c my_ID_file`</strike>

Solution: `dos2unix my_ID_file`

take #2: `readarray` does not remove the line's newline by default. You really want

```
readarray -t TIDs < my_ID_file
```

reference: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-mapfile